# Counting sub-headings in org-mode using elisp

Tags: org-mode, elisp, outline

I'm wondering if there is a good method of counting subheadings of a particular heading in org-mode.  For example, with the following, return `4` (non-recursively) or `7` (recursively).  Note that I don't want to use keywords (ex: `TODO`) and `[/]` syntax (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372550/orgmode-show-number-of-children-under-heading); I just want to calculate it programmatically using elisp.

[image: sample org-mode outline]

I'm hoping that I'm just missing a useful org function.  Otherwise I may resort to counting results of a regex search using the outline patterns of levels `^\\*{n}` bounded by the heading and `org-forward-heading-same-level`.  This is messy and I'd like to do it the "org way" in case org mode ever ignores heading patterns found in source blocks or edge cases I haven't considered.

Comment: Even if `elisp` is used programmatically, *something* is still being counted -- e.g., the number of headings with a given number of stars (e.g., a particular level in the outline), the keywords, or the number of stars and keywords.  Org-mode uses regex -- it's just a little complicated, that's all.

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-04/msg00567.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The org function you are looking for is `org-map-entries`.

```el
(org-map-entries FUNC &optional MATCH SCOPE &rest SKIP)
```

This calls function for each heading determined by MATCH and SCOPE
and returns a list of all return values. Thus

```el
(1-  (length (org-map-entries nil nil 'tree)))
```

returns the number of subentries of the heading at point. To get something a little bit more sophisticated, use FUNC:

```el
(defun org-number-of-subentries (&optional pos match scope level)
  "Return number of subentries for entry at POS.
MATCH and SCOPE are the same as for `org-map-entries', but
SCOPE defaults to 'tree.
By default, all subentries are counted; restrict with LEVEL."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (or pos (point)))
    ;; If we are in the middle ot an entry, use the current heading.
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (let ((maxlevel (when (and level (org-current-level))
                      (+ level (org-current-level)))))
      (message "%s subentries"
               (1- (length
                    (delq nil
                          (org-map-entries
                           (lambda ()
                             ;; Return true, unless below maxlevel.
                             (or (not maxlevel)
                                 (<= (org-current-level) maxlevel)))
                           match (or scope 'tree)))))))))
```

The idea here is to call `org-map-entries` and have the function return true for any heading, you want to count.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function that will count the subheadings (which works more generally for `outline-mode`, and therefore for `org-mode`, which is built on top of `outline-mode`).  You could, presumably, write a more elegant version, but this one works fine:

```
(defun outline-count-subheadings ()
  "Count the number of subheadings below the current heading."
  (let ((sum 0)
        (end (save-excursion
               (ignore-errors
                 (outline-end-of-subtree)
                 (point)))))
    (when end
      (save-excursion 
        (while (and (outline-next-heading)
                    (< (point) end)
                    (setf sum (1+ sum))))
        sum))))
```

Comment: I like the use of org (outline) movement-- a good DRY solution for a user function.  This is probably more efficient than org-map-entries (suggested by @olaf-b), but isn't as neatly generalizable.

Comment: This solution is about 10 times slower than using org-map-entries for a file that's 1.5MB with about 70 "hits" with several thousand headings. In a brief testing, it became apparent that it would be hard to beat the built-in API on efficiency, which org-map-entries is based on.