# How to display sub-heading count somewhere in a heading in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Original title: How to display sub-heading count in the end of a heading in org-mode

It would be very helpful if such a feature can be acheived. I always have difficulty when visiting a long-time not visited org file, where it may have lots of headings and their sub-headings, and so on.

I need to have an overall grasp of which headings have sub-headings when they are collapsed. Since, headings and sub-headings are a lot, so I'm used to only showing first-level headings and opening up a certain heading when I know exactly that it has sub-headings. If I use C-Tab, all second-level sub-headings of first-headings will be shown up, which adds more obstacle for navigating!

In ideal, sub-headings of their parent heading should also have a sub-heading count in the end of them.

I saw this post [Counting sub-headings in org-mode using elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10245/counting-sub-headings-in-org-mode-using-elisp) in emacs.stackchange.com, where the adopted answer implemented a function to print the total count of all the sub-headings of a heading are, where the cursor is at.

For example:

```
* First-level heading that has sub-headings [5]...
    ** Sub-heading1 that has its own sub-headings [3]...
        *** Heading1 [0]...
            Just some text
        *** Heading2 [1]...
            Some text
            **** Heading1 [0]...
                Just some text
    ** Sub-heading 2 [0]...
        Just some text
```

It would be more intuitive, only to show count of sub-headings, but not recursively, as follows:

```
* First-level heading that has sub-headings [2]...
    ** Sub-heading1 that has its own sub-headings [2]...
        *** Heading1 [0]...
            Just some text
        *** Heading2 [1]...
            Some text
            **** Heading1 [0]...
                Just some text
    ** Sub-heading 2 [0]...
        Just some text
```

Note: The behavior of ellipsis should be the default, the example above where the ellipsis is displayed when headings are expanded, is for better demonstration.

Is it possible to add it to each heading indicating how many sub-headings a heading has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: A big thank to @dalanicolai for most of the work to refactor the original code to perfection.

It toggles refreshing of sub-entry counts when an org-file is opened or saved to file.

Here's final version of the code by @dalanicolai which does not create superfluous overlay objects, and where the count displaying position is customizable (see comments):

```lisp
(defcustom org-subentry-count-at-start nil
  "Show the subentry count before the title, not after."
  :group 'org-subenty-count
  :type 'boolean)

(defvar org-subentry-count-in-headings-p nil
  "t to enable org-subentry-count-in-headings
     nil to disable org-subentry-count-in-headings")

(defun org-subentry-count-in-headings ()
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
       (let* ((group (if org-subentry-count-at-start 1 0))
              (beg (match-beginning group))
          (end (match-end group))
              (level (length (match-string 1))) ; stars in headline
              (subheading-count (format "%s" (1- (length (org-map-entries nil nil 'tree)))))
              (ov (car (seq-filter
                        ;; search for subentry-count overlay
                        (lambda (o)
                          (eq (overlay-get o 'type) 'subentry-count)) 
                        (overlays-in (line-beginning-position)
                     (line-end-position))))))
         (if ov ; only create overlay if not exists yet
         (move-overlay ov beg end)
           (setq ov (make-overlay beg end))
           (overlay-put ov 'type 'subentry-count) ; add a type, for easy filtering
           (overlay-put ov 'evaporate t))
         ;; only add/remove 'after-string' prop in toggle
         (if org-subentry-count-in-headings-p
             (overlay-put ov 'after-string (propertize (format " [%s]" subheading-count)
                                                       'face (intern-soft (format "org-level-%d" level))))
           (overlay-put ov 'after-string nil)))))))

(defun toggle-org-subentry-count-in-headings ()
  (interactive)
  (if org-subentry-count-in-headings-p
      (setq org-subentry-count-in-headings-p nil)
    (setq org-subentry-count-in-headings-p t))
  (org-subentry-count-in-headings))

(defun toggle-org-subentry-position ()
  (interactive)
  (setq org-subentry-count-at-start (not org-subentry-count-at-start))
  (setq org-subentry-count-in-headings-p t)
  (org-subentry-count-in-headings))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (setq org-subentry-count-in-headings-p t)
                           (org-subentry-count-in-headings)
                           (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-subentry-count-in-headings)))
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Looks nice, but your code does not work yet, because the `ov-` (ov-make, ov-clear) functions have not been defined...

Comment: I don't know where the `ov-` functions come from, did you define them yourself? Or are they part of some library? Then just mention also that library...

Comment: @dalanicolai I learned it from https://github.com/emacsorphanage/ov

Comment: Okay great... after installing that package, your code works. Just add the info about the dependency (including a link to that package), and add the (require 'ov) add the start of your code. Nice work!

Comment: I have edited the code to remove the `ov` dependency.

Comment: And I have made the hooks to be added locally instead of globally. B.t.w. look at the edits, to see how to get the 'lisp' code highlighting. Also, try to remember to do `M-x untabify` on your code before you post it :)

Comment: It works great, thank you! I have a question, is it right to use "dolist" in "org-map-entries"? It feels a bit off, isn't org-map-entries already a loop over all the headings? why can't I prevent overlay accumulating without dolist, if I do, all overlays will be deleted each time, making this implementation not work

Comment: You are only deleting the overlays between `beg` and `end`. Generally, this will be only the headline overlay, but I guess, sometimes, there could also be other overlays in that region. So you would have to filter for the right overlay somehow. I think you are doing this effectively with the `dolist` i.c.w. `when` (you are only deleting all overlays with an 'after-string' in the region, which generally will be only the single headline overlay). So it looks perfectly fine to me...

Comment: I've updated the code again. The manual mentions that overlay objects do not get deleted when using `delete-overlay`. So, I would say, to prevent creating new overlay objects all the time, it is better to just keep them in place, and only add/remove the `after-string` on toggle. Good luck with your further improvements. It's a nice feature! B.t.w, I think you could accept your own answer by now ;)

Comment: And I moved the count to after the heading (as in the examples in your question).

Comment: Unfortunately, retrieving the face from the heading face does not work reliably, because the heading gets fontified via font-lock (I guess). So instead, I am 'calculating' the face from the heading level (for explanation, take a look at the last edit). I don't fully understand why, when placing the overlay at the beginning, the face gets 'inherited', but not when placing it at the end.

Comment: B.t.w, there exists also this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372929/6837095

Comment: Putting the count at the end of a heading makes this feature less useful though, as it's more difficult to see counts when in a sidebar or the buffer window is not wide enough to display the heading in one line, since I'm used to cutting off the continuous line of a heading at the edge of the window. Yeah, I also encountered not to be able to set face attributes for the overlay, like setting to inherit "fixed-pitch" or just a mono font, weird

Comment: Ah okay, no problem to change it back of course. However, I don't know of any undo feature. So I guess you just have to copy text from the edits, and paste it in a new edit.

Comment: No problem, that's also a nice solution! I'll just also place the original code along with it

Comment: I made the displaying position customizable/toggleable (and slightly modified/updated the text in the answer). You could remove the original code and the text that explains the difference if you like (to make the answer cleaner), or you could keep it as it is now. Whatever you prefer :)

Comment: @dalanicolai You could actually post your own answer, so people can vote and give credits to yours. And I'll change my answer in responce to that. Actually, you've done so much work for this. You do whatever you want. I'm so grateful and speechless. Thank you, my friend:) By the way, setting LOCAL to t for add-hook makes it not able to take effect for org-mode-hook, weird, removing it works.

Comment: I think you did the main part of the work, so it is totally fine that you get the credits. If you prefer separate answers, then let me know, but otherwise, I prefer to keep it to be just some small edits to your answer. Indeed, making the 'org-mode-hooks' local is a mistake, it should have been the 'after-save-hook', which I removed from the answer anyway. Thanks, for pointing it out.

Comment: Why are there two `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook ...)` calls, one local and the other global? Is that an oversight or is it intended (in which case I'd like an explanation please)?

Comment: Fixed and tested, maybe because it was simply by mistake.